# Understanding the Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials within the context of proving $\pi$ transcendental

Tags: pi, symmetric-polynomials, transcendence-theory

I am currently studying the proof of the transcendence of $\pi$. There are a bunch of proofs scattered across the web ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), [here](http://planetmath.org/proofoflindemannweierstrasstheoremandthateandpiaretranscendental), and [here](http://www.math.sc.edu/~filaseta/gradcourses/Math785/Math785Notes6.pdf), to list some); some derive from the Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem, while some are given standalone. But all of them take essentially the same approach, perhaps with some rewording.

My question is not on the proof as a whole, but on a particular segment. It would appear that a key element here is a (double) application of the Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials. I have tried to understand this concept using [info from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), but I cannot quite wrap my head around it, or how exactly it works out in the proof.

I was hoping someone could give me a graspable explanation of this theorem, and perhaps an elucidation as to how it applies to the proof. It would also help a lot if someone could give me an application of this theorem to an easy example (i.e., using it outside the context of the proof) so I can get a concrete feel for it. Thanks.

Comment: Floating around in various places, there are many, many problems of the type "Find $p(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$, where $\{z_i\}$ are the roots of the $n$th degree polynomial $f(x)$" where $p$ is some explicit symmetric polynomial. The reason we are able to compute this expression exactly in terms of the coefficients of $f$ is the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials. On top of the fundamental theorem this employs Vieta's formulas, which tells us that up to sign factors the coefficients of $f$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials of the roots.

Comment: If you are looking through the proof of pi's being transcendental, you may be interested in the answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21367/proof-that-pi-is-transcendental-that-doesnt-use-the-infinitude-of-primes

Comment: @anon could you give an example of one of those "Find p(z1,⋯,zn), where {zi} are the roots of the nth degree polynomial f(x)" ? It would really help.

Comment: Sure. Find $a^3+b^3+c^3$ where $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3-x^2+1$. You may find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly (and perhaps somewhat obviously), symmetric polynomials are useful because they are exactly those which are invariant under all [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) of the variables. There are a lot of situations where we consider what happens if we switch around the roles of the $x_i$.

The Fundamental Theorem tells us that there is a convenient basis for symmetric polynomials, namely, the "elementary symmetric polynomials" (these are the ones $x_1 + \dotsb + x_n,\, \sum_{i<j}x_ix_j,\, $etc.)

> **Example:** Suppose $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \dotsb + z^n\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ is a polynomial over the complex numbers (or, if you want more generality, over an algebraically closed field). We can write $p(z) = \prod_{i}(z-\alpha_i)$ for $\alpha_i$ the roots. Then I claim the coefficients $a_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots $\alpha_j$. For instance, $a_0 = \prod_i \alpha_ i$ and $a_{n-1} = \alpha _1 + \dotsb + \alpha_n$. Now, the fundamental theorem tells us that if we have **any** symmetric polynomial in the $\alpha_i$ (for example, the *discriminant*), then this can be written in terms of the coefficients $a_i$.

Is it the abstract algebra (rings, isomorphisms, etc.) which is confusing you?

Sorry my answer is not more in depth, hope this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "convenient basis"?

Comment: @Coffee_Table Suppose $s_1, \dotsc, s_n$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials. The theorem says that any symmetric polynomial can be written as $a_1s_1 + a_2s_2 + \dotsb + a_ns_n$, where $a_i$ are elements of the ring in question (suppose they are real numbers, for example). Then, if we have a property $P$ which we want to say holds for all symmetric polynomials $p$, and the property is linear and scalable, so $P(p_1)$ and $P(p_2)$ implies $P(p_1 + p_2)$ and $P(ap_1)$ and $P(ap_2)$, then it suffices to check $P$ on the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: @Coffee_Table That is pretty convenient, since there are a finite number of elementary symmetric polynomials, but there are infinitely many symmetric polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article entitled "The Powers of Pi are Irrational."  It gives a development of the transcendence of pi using easier irrationality proofs.  Just google the title and it comes up.